# How to remove the "implements" gutter icon in WebStorm 2018.2?

Tags: icons, settings, webstorm, gutter

If I uncheck "show gutter icons" will hide the 4 icons in the image. But that will remove all icons, I still want to keep the colors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can't be currently disabled, please vote for [WEB-32824](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32824) to be notified on any progress with this feature.
You can hide all gutter icons at once by disabling **Show gutter icons** in **Settings | Editor | General | Gutter Icons**